# Exporting Redmine Production Log into Excel or CSV

Tags: redmine

AS the title goes, is there any way I can export Redmine production log into Excel or CSV? I need the production logs for viewing the users that logged-in in a certain time frame, the pages they viewed and the changes they may have made. The log file is a big chunk of text that would take be time consuming to parse.

Comment: If you want to investigate the logged-in times, this is a privacy violation if your users are not aware of your intend.

Comment: My users are fully aware of my intention, in fact, it is our executive committee that wants an audit trail for our Redmine server so we would be able to check if there are unauthorized accesses to the server.

Comment: Glad to hear this :-) To be honest I don't know of a way to access this data. Isn't everything logged into MySQL or PostgreSQL ?

Comment: We're using MySQL for the database and sadly, upon checking the mysql logs, what I could make up of it were SELECT queries. I was looking at the mysqld-slow-query.log file. I didn't find anything regarding user access logging. Thanks for the suggestion though, had to check it.

Comment: Redmine doesn't write to the mysql log file but Redmine inserts into the database.

Comment: Aside from the production logs of Redmine, is there anywhere in MySQL that I might be able to access what I'm looking for? Maybe there would be a way to export that file. From my Google search, there isn't any result coming up that could solve my problem.

Comment: [Redmine Database Model](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/DatabaseModel) <- this is all I can do. There is plenty of information in it. Not sure if it covers all your needs.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Thank you very much for considering to comment and for the Database Model. I'll look into it and see if anything there might help.